# appended node not appearing in xml file

Tags: xml, dom, append, nodes

I have a `units.xml` file that looks like this

```
 <dbms>
    <units>
        <UNITID>1</UNITID>
        <TYPE>Administrative Office</TYPE>
        <UNITINITIALS>OAA</UNITINITIALS>
        <UNITNAME>Office of Alumni Affairs</UNITNAME>
    </units>
    <units>
     .... and so on
 </dbms>
```

I want to append a new element `LOCATION` to the node and I do so using this code:

```
<script>
  var xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("units.xml");
  x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('units');
  x[0].setAttribute("LOCATION","Ground Floor");

  document.write("Location: ");
  document.write(x[0].getAttribute("LOCATION"));
</script>
```

It prints out what I want it to ("`Location: Ground Floor`") but when I open my `units.xml` file, nothing has changed. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Java script is not a server side language , however php can deal with that

```
<?php
define("UPLOADEDFILES", " url of units.xml ");
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$xmlfile=UPLOADEDFILES."units.xml";
if(is_file($xmlfile)){   // test if file exists
  $doc->load($xmlfile);
  $Dbms = $doc->getElementsByTagName("dbms");
  $root = $Dbms->item(0);
} else{  // if file does not exists
 $root = $doc->createElement('dbms');
 $doc->appendChild($root);
 $UNITS = $doc->createElement("units");
 $root->appendChild($UNITS);
} 
$units=$root->getElementsByTagName("units")->item(0);
$units->setAttribute("LOCATION","blablabla");//append the attribute LOCATION to the first units node 

 //you can append the attribute wherever you want , just follow the previous example

$doc->save($xmlfile); // save changes
?>
```